# Remove the white background on app drawer on Android 5.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, app-drawer

Is there a way we can remove the white background that shows up forever behind the icons on Android. I read somewhere that Android 6 Developer options may provide that. If someone figured it out on Android 5, please advise.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Are you using the stock launcher?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98337/set-the-background-image-of-the-main-menu-in-lollipop/

Answer (score 3):

This is very much possible, but you will require a custom launcher. For the sake of this, we'll use [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher).

1. Install Nova Launcher and set it as the default when going back to your Home screen.

   [image]
2. Go to the "App & Widget Drawers" screen in Nova settings and scroll down to find the options shown in image. Make sure the switch for "Card background" is set to off.

   [image]